# How is machine epsilon calculated?

Tags: c++, floating-point, precision

Machine Epsilon for 32-Bit Float ISO-C Standard is: **1.19209e-07** 
The max Float is: **3.40282e+38**

How is the machine epsilon derived from float max?

I have used this snippet to get the values:

```
std::cout<<std::numeric_limits<float>::max()<<std::endl;
std::cout<<std::numeric_limits<float>::epsilon()<<std::endl;
```

Comment: See http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: It isn't derived from the max value. It's derived from the size of the mantissa.

Comment: Just look in your compiler's header files.  You'll see it isn't "derived", it is hard-coded.  Very little hardware left that doesn't use IEEE-754.

Comment: Hey Hans, thanks for that, but if i would like to calculate it... is there an easy way for that?

Comment: Well, sure, compute log(1.19209e-07) / log(2) and wonder a bit why this is a nice round number and what it means.  Then just do the opposite.

Answer (score 2):

> How is the machine epsilon derived from float max?

You could derive the machine epsilon of an IEEE 754-like binary floating-point system from the maximum finite float by observing that, the maximum finite float is written 1.111<n binary digits one> * 2<sup>e<sub>max</sub></sup>.

In these conditions, the machine epsilon is, in binary, 0.000<n-1 binary digits zero>1.

However, the maximum finite float and the machine epsilon are really different parameters that capture different characteristics of a floatin-point system: the range of values that can be represented with finite approximations, and the precision of these approximations.

EDIT: by request from the OP, a skeletal implementation:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <float.h>

int main(void) {
  printf("%a\n", FLT_MAX);
  printf("FLT_MAX is 0x1.fffffep+127 therefore machine epsilon must be:\n");
  printf("           0x0.000002p0 that is approx %e in decimal\n", 0x0.000002p0);
}
```

On my platform I get the result:

```
0x1.fffffep+127
FLT_MAX is 0x1.fffffep+127 therefore machine epsilon must be:
           0x0.000002p0 that is approx 1.192093e-07 in decimal
```

Since the entire exercise is utterly pointless, the actual computation of the machine epsilon from `FLT_MAX` is left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: Thanks Pascla, could you write a complete example? I read that there are iterative approaches to get the machine epsilon, so your mentioned method is accurate? binary digits zero = 32?

Comment: @user1767754:  `std::numeric_limits` is defined at compile time (usually by somebody reading the hardware spec and working it out).  Why would you want a runtime approach?  Something like `double eps=1.0;  while (1.0 + eps != 1.0) eps /= 2; eps *= 2;`will do (except you have to make sure the addition and comparison are done in double, not long double).

Comment: I just want to know it out of curiosity...basically the numeric_limit is the minimum number on a "yard-stick" right? So i thought if you know how long the yard-stick is in units this divided by 1 would give you eps? but i think i am overthinking sth.

Comment: @user1767754 You should read http://floating-point-gui.de/ until you understand how floating-point works. Your yardstick analogy is wrong.